# Fields in Java. Difference between Field and Method

Tags: java

What is meant by Field in Java? I have Googled about this, I got some answers but I couldn't understand. What is the difference between Field and Method. Is enum associated with field in java? I find _ACTIVE, _DISCARDING, _HOLDING and many as fields in java.

Comment: [Please read a tutorial on classes and objects.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: First hit in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28computer_science%29

Comment: I know about classes and objects. I could not understand about fields.

Comment: @BalaSubramanyam What confuses you in this subject? Can you update your question with more details?

Comment: @BalaSubramanyam You don't know about classes if you don't know about fields. Please read the whole tutorial about classes, fields are explained.

Comment: Fields are members that hold data. You may know them as "member variables" or "instance variables".

Comment: When we speak of data hiding in OO, it's the fields that are hidden. The methods are what manipulates the class' field values (again speaking about OO).

Comment: @m0skit0 Actually I know what they are. I confused a little.I am aware of those with other terminology. Thanks!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Yes you are absolutely correct. I am aware of them as member variables and instance variables

Comment: @Pshemo When I go through the java documentation in DASH on my mac, I find these categories (Classes, Interfaces, Packages, Exceptions, Errors, Constructors, Methods, Fields) Except Fields I can identify every other category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field is a member variable that belongs to a class.

A method is a set of java commands referred to by name.  You are able to execute all the commands by using the name of the method.  Methods can take values as parameters and return a value as a result.

An Enum is a special datatype somewhere between a regular primitive datatype and a class.

And you should definitely read the tutorial on what a class is.

Answer (score 3):

- **Member :** Normally used to define the variables and methods.
- **Attribute :** Attributes are the instance variables of an Object.
- **Variable :** Primitive variables and Objects reference variables as instance or local variables.
- **Field :** Field marks an instance variable.
- **Method :** Function defined in class